# Is write mode pipe synchronous?

Tags: linux, pipe

Will the following code wait for the command execution to finish before abort() is called?
In case it doesn't and the parent process is aborted, will the child(the bash shell) be alive and continue the execution of the command.

```
FILE *_popenShell = NULL;
_popenShell = popen("/bin/bash","w");
fwrite("some_command", 1, SOME_SIZE, _popenShell);
fflush(_popenShell);        
pclose(_popenShell);        
abort();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pclose()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pclose.3.html) waits until the child terminates (using `wait4()`). Child should not be running by the time you hit `abort()`.